# Sorting python pandas dataframe with respect to a column of type object

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I've got a dataframe that looks like the following (subset):

```
0        2014-01-23 17:01:09
1000     2014-01-23 17:38:28
2000     2014-01-23 18:08:28
3000     2014-01-23 18:33:10
4000     2014-01-24 14:19:28
5000     2014-01-24 14:31:04
6000     2014-01-23 18:34:53
7000     2014-01-23 17:15:36
8000     2014-01-23 19:31:45
9000     2014-01-23 19:23:06
10000    2014-01-23 17:58:15
Name: date, dtype: object
```

As you can see the column type of column `date` is `object`. So, I'd like to sort this column chronologically. Therefore in my code I call

```
data = data.sort(['date'])
```

however, the result looks like this:

```
0        2014-01-23 17:01:09
1000     2014-01-23 17:38:28
2000     2014-01-23 18:08:28
3000     2014-01-23 18:33:10
4000     2014-01-24 14:19:28
5000     2014-01-24 14:31:04
6000     2014-01-23 18:34:53
7000     2014-01-23 17:15:36
8000     2014-01-23 19:31:45
9000     2014-01-23 19:23:06
10000    2014-01-23 17:58:15
Name: date, dtype: object
```

So, nothing was sorted. But why does it not work?

UPDATE: I now found the following stuff on the internet:

```
import dateutil
data['date'] = data['date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
print str(data.dtypes)
```

yields:

```
date        datetime64[ns]
```

However, even now that the type is explicitly set to a datetime object I'm still not able to sort it chronologically. Now, I'm really confused.

UPDATE 2:
Now I did the following in the code

```
    data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
    data = data.sort(['date'])
```

However, it still has no effect. No sorting w.r.t. date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I now found out. The index of the dataframe is also permutated according to the sorting order of the dataframe. So, the output of

```
print str(data['date'].ix[np.array(range(0,11))*1000])
print str(data[:20])
```

actually is different. Therefore I did not see any effect on the sorting, although everything was properly sorted already. However, this is extremly counter intuitive!

In order to create a corrected index order one can repair the permutation by:

```
data = data.sort(['date'])
data.index = range(0,len(data))
```

ADDITIONAL COMMENT: Actually it would be great if in the documentation of pandas there would be a remark on such a pitfall (and others). It nearly drove me crazy and only a collegue knew this by coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, this help me a lot.

Only thing I noticed is

```
data = data.sort(['date'])
```

Is now deprecated it should be:

```
data = data.sort_values(by='date')
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date to pandas datetime.
like:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: I additionally applied `data['date'] = data['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)`. It has not effect on the sorting of the frame.

Comment: hopefully you figured this out by now, but I think the trick here is that you have to move the datetime column into the index. Then you can sort the whole dataframe by that column, and move it back. It's cumbersome, but it works.